# Is there a Jupyter code that I can use "to stop" a Notebook Instances on Sagemaker, after running any code?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, instance, shutdown, amazon-sagemaker

I use a Jupyter Notebook instance on Sagemaker to run a code that took around 3 hours to complete. Since I pay for hour use, I would like to automatically "Close and Halt" the Notebook as well as stop the "Notebook instance" after running that code. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter Notebook are predominantly designed for exploration and
   development. If you want to launch long-running or scheduled jobs on
   ephemeral hardware, it will be a much better experience to use the
   training API, such as the [`create_training_job`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_training_job) in boto3 or the
   `estimator.fit()` of the [Python SDK](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/estimators.html). The code passed to training jobs
   can be completely arbitrary - not necessarily ML code - so whatever
   you write in jupyter could likely be scheduled and ran in those
   training jobs. See the [random forest sklearn demo here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_randomforest/Sklearn_on_SageMaker_end2end.ipynb) for an
   example. That being said, if you still want to programmatically shut
   down a SageMaker notebook instance, you can use that boto3 call:

```
import boto3

sm = boto3.client('sagemaker')
sm.stop_notebook_instance(NotebookInstanceName='string')
```

Comment: Thank you @Oliver_Cruchant, your advice will be very useful for me.